# Invalid use of null value Access 2007

Tags: null, ms-access-2007

I was doing this query when I got an invalid use of null value error:

```
SELECT Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni.[Numero Inventario], CInt([Numero Inventario]) AS Espr1
FROM Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni INNER JOIN PC_CarelHQ_modificato ON CInt(Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni.[Numero Inventario])=PC_CarelHQ_modificato.[n inv];
```

In the Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni table the primary key "Numero Inventario" is text, so I was doing a cast on it, because in the other table it is an integer (it is an index so there is no decimal stuff).

I Had moreover two other alternatives to make it works.

i)  SELECT Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni.[Numero Inventario], Val(Nz(Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni.[Numero Inventario]," ")) AS Espr1 FROM Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni INNER JOIN PC_CarelHQ_modificato ON Val(Nz(Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni.[Numero Inventario])," "))=PC_CarelHQ_modificato.[n inv];

which gives me a mistake about a wrong number of arguments in Val(..........)

ii) SELECT Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni.[Numero Inventario], Val(Nz(Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni.[Numero Inventario],0)) AS Espr1 FROM Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni INNER JOIN PC_CarelHQ_modificato ON Val(Nz(Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni.[Numero Inventario]),0))=PC_CarelHQ_modificato.[n inv];

which gives me the same mistake as i) !

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you what the problem is. The text column that you are converting to an integer and then using as join fields is your problem - Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni.[Numero Inventario]

Search for Nulls on this column, or filter it out in your query before converting it to an int.

Comment: Yes I have some null values, and in theory I can't ignore those records and I can't update them because the tables are linked from excel to access and I can work on the just in reading mode. Thanks

Comment: Have you got any suggestion to solve the trouble with a query? I can make a copy from the original table and I should insert the query with the solution into the new table! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to Manage a null value on NumeroInventario before casting it to Int.

```
Try CInt(Nz(Numero Inventario, 0))
```

And let me know if it solve the issue.

Try this:

SELECT Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni.[Numero Inventario], Val(Nz([Numero Inventario],0)) AS Espr1
FROM Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni INNER JOIN PC_CarelHQ_modificato ON Val(Nz(Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni.[Numero Inventario]),0))=PC_CarelHQ_modificato.[n inv];

You need to Manage null value and replace them with 0 (make sure that you don't have any n_inv with 0 as value) Also it's better if you use Val, since CInt would fail if it receive an empty string

Comment: Well, making a cast in the ON condition in the inner join, makes me weird. Where may I insert your suggestion in the query? Thanks

Comment: It gives me an error about a wrong number of arguments in the val() function. How may I correct it?

Comment: well, If I set at zero where is null, then Numero Inventario is no longer a primary key, because there are more than 2 records with code zero. I think your solution is not good in this case!

Comment: But they won't join any value from "PC_CarelHQ_modificato" since it's an INNER JOIN and in CarelHq there are NO 0 record.

Comment: I also tried to put " ", where there is the zero in Nz(...) but It gives me a mistake about a wrong number of argouments put in the function Val(....). Also in this case I have got the trouble about the primary key. Do you have any suggestion? Thank you so much

Comment: I also made a left join query, between the same 2 tables and I'll give you the solution that is actually working somehow but still with something wrong. In PC_CarelHQ_modificato I have got all the values and how It was expected, just some of them match with Lansweeper. At the end of the data extracted from the query, in PC_CarelHQ_modificato I have got a lonf list of "# error" with a number in same case for Lansweeper.

Comment: There is my solution: SELECT CStr(PC_CarelHQ_modificato.[n inv]) AS PC_CarelHQ_jacopoBelloni_num_inv, Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni.[Numero Inventario] FROM PC_CarelHQ_modificato LEFT JOIN Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni ON CStr(PC_CarelHQ_modificato.[n inv])=Lansweeper_jacopoBelloni.[Numero Inventario];